# jQuery: Hide all divs except the child of currently hovered item

Tags: jquery

I'm using some code from Chris Coyer for fly-out menus:

```
$(function(){

$(".mega-menu li").hover(function(){

    $(this).addClass("hover"); // Add a .hover class to this item.
    $(".mega-menu li").not(this).removeClass("hover"); // Remove the hover class from all others.
    $('div:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible'); // Reveal the currently hovered item's flyout menu.

}, function(){

    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('div:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); // Hide the currently hovered item's flyout menu.

});

});
```

I've noticed that on an iPad, if I follow a link in a fly-out menu, then I hit the back button, that fly-out menu remains visible, even after I click on another item. I assume that I need to tell something like "when the user hovers over an item, hide all fly-out menus other than the child of that item."

Does that sound right? How might I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: It would most likely be a result of the inability to use hover classes on touch devices... Try changing `.hover()` to `.click()` and see what happens?

Comment: When I do that, touching the link just follows it to its destination (I do want 'landing pages' that can be reached if the user clicks the link twice, so I can't change the href to "#").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem. There are multiple solutions.
For example: you can use a flag.

Read here:

http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/

and here:

http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/